# matlab: inefficient "mysum"

Tags: performance, matlab, sum

in order to estimate some non-linear models, i need to derive a quite huge function numerically. one part of the target function includes a polynomial (which is created by some sums).
there are quite a lot of iterations in this process and my computer takes way to much time to compute (though it yields reasonable estimates). the profiler claims, that my handwritten sum-function is by far the most time-consuming part of the algorithm. this is my first matlab project, so im pretty new to it. maybe you can help to optimize it :)

```
 function [output] = mysum(a,b,inputfun)
   output=0;
   for i=a:b
        output=ouput+inputfun(i);
   end
```

if you want to know, how i use it. this is the polynomial:

```
function [ weights ] = wexpo(theta)
global lag;

for i=1:lag
    weights(i) = exp(mysum(1,length(theta),@(k) theta(k)*(i-1)^k))...
                 /mysum(0,lag-1,@(j)...
                 exp(mysum(1,length(theta),@(k) theta(k)*j^k)));
end
```

Comment: Maybe, but what is `inputfun`? It would help a lot if you edited your question to provide representative values for `a`, `b`, and `inputfun`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Matlab functions:

```
function [output] = mysum(a,b,inputfun)
    output = sum(inputfun(a:b))
```

Comment: @Antalagor And if you replace the function call by `sum(inputfun(a:b))` directly perhaps you can save some more time

Comment: well,
can anyone help me to implement this into my anonymous functions? or in other words how do i put the dots right?

Comment: ok guys - got it. had to work abit around. but finally this command helped a lot and my script is way faster now. thank you!